# explain the basic principals behind a nuget server and nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, nuget

Can someone explain the basic principals behind a nuget server and nuget packages. I've only used nuget in Visual studio to download things like nunit and other add-ons to enhance my visual studio experience. However, it seems a lot more powerful than this. For instance integration with other systems, e.g. TeamCity, Octopus for one-click deployment etc. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is indeed capable to be a lot more than "just" a package manager. 
I just want to give you some more pointers to resources that might help you:

- I've written quite a few [blog posts on NuGet](http://www.xavierdecoster.com), including one covering [the whole NuGet ecosystem](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/09/30/an-overview-of-the-nuget-ecosystem)
- There's a book on NuGet ([Apress Pro NuGet](http://bit.ly/ProNuGet)): it also covers Chocolatey, OctopusDeploy, and web architecture using NuGet as a protocol.
- There is also [MyGet.org](http://www.myget.org) (NuGet-as-a-Service)

Hope these help you getting the best out of NuGet.